# What are some programming related topics that can be solved using NLP?

Tags: natural-language-processing

I've been working on the Punctuation Restoration Problem for my Master's Thesis, however, me being primarily a programmer at heart, I wish I could use some of my NLP skills to solve issues related to programming in general.

I know Microsoft does lots of research in NLP and I think after they acquired Github, they have an immense dataset to work with for any problems related to programming they want to tackle. Most recently I think they did a great job on their new python suggestion extension on VSCode.

So, could you suggest to me some issues you think are interesting research topics? This is something that I would like to work with, but I have no idea where to start yet.

Comment: Look into the https://www.decoder-project.eu/ project

Comment: Also look into the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project and consider using it for your Master's thesis and contributing to it. See also [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/15661/3335)