# Are CNN, LSTM, GRU and transformer AGI or computational intelligence tools?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, agi

Will CNN, LSTM, GRU and transformer be better classified as Computational Intelligence (CI) tools or Artificial General Intelligence (AGI) tools? The term CI arose back when some codes like neural networks, GA, PSO were considered doing magical stuff. These days CI tools do not appear very magical. Researchers want codes to exude AGI. Do the current state of art Deep Learning codes fall in the AGI category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNNs, LSTMs, GRUs and transformers are or use artificial neural networks. The expression *computational intelligence* (CI) is often used interchangeably with *artificial intelligence* (AI). CI can also refer to a subfield or superfield of AI where biology is often an inspiration. See [What is Computational Intelligence and what could it become?](http://cogprints.org/5358/1/06-CIdef.pdf) by Włodzisław Duch.

RNNs are [Turing complete](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221142/82135) and [CNNs have been shown to be universal function approximators](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/13319/2444) (they can approximate any continuous function to an arbitrary accuracy given a sufficiently deep architecture), but that doesn't mean we will be able to create AGI with them, unless you believe that AGI is just a bunch of algorithms, but, IMHO, that alone doesn't produce AGI. See also [the computational theory of mind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-mind/).

To conclude, CNNs, LSTMs, GRUs and transformers are deep learning tools (so they could also be considered CI tools, given some definitions of CI), which *might* be useful for the development of AGI.

Comment: how would you differentiate between CI,AI,AGI?

Comment: @user_1_1_1 AGI is a sub-field of AI that attempts to develop AGI (intelligent systems similar to humans). As I say in my answer, AI can be used interchangeably with CI, but not all people will agree with this usage. I recommend you read the paper I cite in my answer for more details. I also recommend you read my answer [https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/16649/2444](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/16649/2444).